# Does mod_pagespeed use Elacticache Cluster Client? Or do we have to manually keep a list of nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, mod-pagespeed, amazon-elasticache

I've searched a lot for this, but couldn't find anything. The documentation (https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/system#memcached) also does not specify anything regarding the same.

I'm using mod_pagespeed on apache server, and I have a memcached cluster already set up that is being used by some other services. I want to use this cluster for caching with pagespeed using the directive:

ModPagespeedMemcachedServers "host:port"

I want to know if I can use the configuration endpoint (auto-discovery of nodes) of the memcached cluster here in place of "host".

So, does pagespeed leverage the auto-discovery using configuration endpoint of ElastiCache Memcached Cluster?

Comment: Since this issue is still open (https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-mod/issues/806), my guess is that this isn't supported yet.